# Error using strjoin

Tags: matlab

so i'm using this example code,

```
 --- Define M
M = [sprintf('%s\t%s\n', 'a', 'b') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '011', '10') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '001', '10') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '112', '4') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '015', '2') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '086', '1') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '117', '1') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '121', '2')]

% --- Convert into cells
tmp = textscan(M, '%s\t%s\n');
C1 = tmp{1};            % First column
C2 = tmp{2};            % Second column

% --- Group

% Get unique values of the second column
UV = unique(C2);

% Prepare result columns
R1 = {};
R2 = {};

% Group
for i = 1:numel(UV)

    b = ismember(C2, UV{i});
    R1{i,1} = strjoin(C1(b), ',');
    R2{i,1} = strjoin(C2(b), ',');

end

% --- Convert the result to a string
Res = '';
for i = 1:numel(R1)
    Res = [Res sprintf('%s\t%s\n', R1{i}, R2{i})];
end
```

but it gives an error: Error using strjoin (line 52)
First input must be a 1xN cell array of strings.

i'm using R2014a version of matlab, i don't know how to fix this error, i really need that code please help thanks.

Comment: is strjoin command compatible in R2009b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also get that error running your code (R2013a). Since `C1` and `C1` are cell arrays of size 8x1 you actually need to transpose both of them to avoid the error (and thus get cell arrays of size 1x8 as requested by `strjoin`). That's a bit stupid that it does not do the transpose by itself.

Add these 2 lines before the loop providing the error and it runs fine:

```
C1 = C1.';
C2 = C2.';
```

Complete code:

```
M = [sprintf('%s\t%s\n', 'a', 'b') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '011', '10') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '001', '10') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '112', '4') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '015', '2') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '086', '1') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '117', '1') ...
    sprintf('%s\t%s\n', '121', '2')]

% --- Convert into cells
tmp = textscan(M, '%s\t%s\n');
C1 = tmp{1};            % First column
C2 = tmp{2};            % Second column

% --- Group

% Get unique values of the second column
UV = unique(C2);

% Prepare result columns
R1 = {};
R2 = {};

C1 = C1.';
C2 = C2.';

% Group
for i = 1:numel(UV)

    b = ismember(C2, UV{i});
    R1{i,1} = strjoin(C1(b), ',');
    R2{i,1} = strjoin(C2(b), ',');

end

% --- Convert the result to a string
Res = '';
for i = 1:numel(R1)
    Res = [Res sprintf('%s\t%s\n', R1{i}, R2{i})];
end
```

Doing so I get

```
Res =

086,117 1,1
011,001 10,10
015,121 2,2
112 4
a   b
```

Comment: Thanks Master! keep it up!

Comment: I don't know you would need to try it to see